# Android drawable

Tags: android

I've a little problem with drawable repertory : I added an image in all drawable repertory (hdpi,ldpi,mdpi,etc ..) but in my file xml, when I wrote

```
android:backgroud="@drawable/fond_ecran"
```

I've this error message : `Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/fond_ecran').`

I don't understand why because the image `fond_ecran.png` is in all drawable repertory so if someone have an explication to give me, it's will be cool :)

Comment: Maybe try to clean the project, that way it will detect new resources as well

Comment: Have You tried to restart eclipse? Clean the project?

Answer (score 1):

> I don't understand why because the image fond_ecran.png is in all
>   drawable repertory so if someone have an explication to give me, it's
>   will be cool :)

At first check if you don't have errors in `XML` and `Java` files(because if you have, `R.java` is not correctly generated) and clean and build your project again. It should solve your problem. If not try to create next folder named `drawable` and put image inside.

Answer (score 0):

**Are the drawables visible from the eclipse IDE in the drawable folder?**

- No? Right click at the project explorer and refresh.

Also try clean the project so it is recreates the Generated files like `R.java`